# i need the footnotes to be correctly aligned at the bottom of the page but they have moved up--why?--can the footnotes be place in the right margin?

Tags: footnotes

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage[table]{xcolor}                      %for color of table
\usepackage{booktabs}                        %for toprule midrule bottomrule in tables
\usepackage{multirow} % Required for multirows
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
%\usepackage{amsmath}
%\usepackage{amsfonts, amsmath, amssymb}                    %maths
%\usepackage{amssymb}

\usepackage[none]{hyphenat}                             %no hyphenation
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{lastpage}                                     %toget last page number
 \usepackage{indentfirst}

\usepackage{stix} % Use the STIX fonts

\newcommand*{\plogo}{\fbox{$\mathcal{PL}$}} % Generic dummy publisher logo 
%\renewcommand*\familydefault{\sfdefault}             %best
\usepackage[
  height=8in,      % height of the text block
  width=6in,       % width of the text block
  top=78pt,        % distance of the text block from the top of the page
  headheight=60pt, % height for the header block
  headsep=12pt,    % distance from the header block to the text block
  heightrounded,   % ensure an integer number of lines
%  showframe,       % show the main blocks
  verbose,         % show the values of the parameters in the log file
]{geometry}
%header and footer
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhead{}
\fancyfoot{}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.1pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.1pt}

\fancyhead[R]{%
            \footnotesize 
                 Special Assignment Wing\\Controllerate of Quality Assurance \\ Armoured Vehicle Electronics\\Avadi, Chennai – 600 054}

\fancyhead[C]{\includegraphics[scale=1]{images/"dgqa logo".png} }
\fancyhead[L]{%
            \footnotesize 
                 File No: 20211/JC/SA dt 17 Sep 2019}
\fancyfoot[L]{%
            \footnotesize 
                 Typeset in \LaTeX}


\begin{document}

                \begin{center}
                    \underline{NOTING SHEET}                    \\
                    \underline{KEY RESULT AREAS: ISO 9001:2015} \\
                \end{center}

\underline{Jt Controller (SA)/MR}\\

\begin{enumerate}
\item Please refer 
\item d \footnote{Flag 4A}. The ed \footnote{Flag 5A}.The al also \footnote{Flag 6A}. \\
\item Record of changes is as below:
\begin{enumerate}
\item Addition
\item Amendment 
\end{enumerate}
\item Placed for perusal .\\
\end{enumerate}



\raggedleft {JS Bibra}\\


\raggedright \underline{Controller}


\end{document}
```

Comment: Check the log file for a warning about the `\headheight`.

Comment: Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph at lines 65--66-secondwarning--Overfull \hbox (9.97252pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 76--77

Comment: all warnings removed but the footnotes are in the middle of the page--the \\ have been removed at places where not required to remove the warnings--compiling correctly but footnotes in the middle of the page

Comment: \usepackage[bottom]{footmisc}-----using the package to send the footnotes down--ok for now-- discussion closed--thankx @egreg